# Character Limit on CSV when running import-csv powershell script

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm running this command line in powershell, and there has been different way the output is saved.

```
Import-csv $path\From.csv | Sort-Object -Property Dirpath | group-object -Property DirPath | Where {$_.Count -eq 1} | select-object @{Name='File'; Expression={$_.Group[0].File}}, Name | Export-Csv -Path $path\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The From.csv contains about 100k or more lines. Sample is below:

"File","DirPath"
"FS","\AR01"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS\PM-60100"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS\PM-60100\Datasheets"
"FD","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS\PM-60100\Datasheets"
"FR","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS"

It should filter out all the similar Dirpath and leave the ones that doesn't have a duplicate. So the Output.csv should look like this.

"File","DirPath"
"FS","\AR01"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL"
"FS","\AR01\BLEND\ELECTRICAL\MOTORS\PM-60100"

The code is working perfectly, except for one thing.
In powershell version 5. When a line reaches 180 characters, the next characters would be chopped to the next line.
When this same code is ran on a version lower (Powershell version 3) the limit is lower. The line would be chopped after the 80th character and would be displayed to the next line.

Is there anyway i can remove the character limit per line regardless the version?

Sorry for the newbie question. The version issue is just a hunch of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change this behaviour by modifying buffer size of console:

```
$pshost = get-host

$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui

$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize

$newsize.height = 3000
#the below value determines the character limit for one line

$newsize.width = 300

$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
```

You can get more details about this from this reference link : 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/12/04/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console/

Answer (score 1):

As well the programmatic solution by Abhijith pk, you can do this by right-clicking on the PowerShell icon and going to properties. This will apply every time you use this shortcut to start a PowerShell console.

[image: Right click > Properties]

When you are describing is the Width screen buffer size limit, under the layout tab. If you don't want horizontal scroll bars, adjust the window size so it is as big or bigger.

[image: Go to layout tab]